# Why does `short a = (byte)32767` become -1?

Tags: java

How is the output of the following Java program calculated?

```
class hello {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        short a=(byte)32767;
        System.out.println(a);      
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, assigning 32767 to a byte (max 127) makes you enter the Undefined Behavior zone.

Comment: another guess is 32767 = `0111 1111`. Hence, casted to a byte, it becomes `1111` (truncated) which is the encoding of `-1`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle it is not undefined behavior. In case of `byte`, it will overflow and a byte with value 127 + 1 will become into -128. Now, just do the same more times depending on how many overflows it will have.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Almost, but twice as many bits (`0111 1111 1111 1111` -> `1111 1111`).

Answer (score 7):

The integer constant 32767 is, in hex, 0x00007FFF.

A `byte` is a signed 8-bit type. Casting `(byte)0x00007FFF` effectively truncates the upper 24 bits, leaving 0xFF.

Since it is signed, this represents -1. Assigning it back to a `short` doesn't change the value because it's already been converted to a `byte`, and -1 is within range of a `short`. The evaluation is essentially:

```
short a = (byte)32767;
short a = (byte)0x00007FFF;
short a = (byte)0xFF (= (byte)(0x00007FFF & 0x000000FF));
short a = -1;
```

Or, binary, if you prefer (since others have been mentioning it):

```
      32767 = 00000000 00000000 01111111 11111111 (type is int)
(byte)32767 = ^-- these are dropped. --^ 11111111 (type is byte)
to short    =                   11111111 11111111 (value is signed [-1], sign extends)
```

It's important to remember that `byte` is signed, so the *signed* value is preserved when widening to a `short`. If `byte` were unsigned (range 0-255) then the value would be 255 and the resulting `short` would be `00000000 11111111` (255).

Comment: "because value is -1" <-- because value is negative, no need for it to be -1 ;)